Turbulence only works until certain frame
I'm making a windy meadow and the grass is strip hair. The wind force seems to work just fine, but the turbulence, despite having the exact same movement replicated through the whole timeline, only affects the grass until around frame 291 no matter what i do. Is there like a life length setting for turbulences or is it some other kinda issue?



pls provide blend file. And no, i don't think there is an issue with turbulences

Did you change the Simulation End frame number under the Cache entry on the Hair Dynamics section of the Particle System to match the end frame of your animation?

yeah it was the cache thing, i didn't know where it could be, thanks!

No problem. I've seen others caught out by that one!
